# How to replace text in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, google-docs

I already have code that works, but the formatting is not preserved. When executing the function, a pop-up window is displayed, the words can be entered here. When the script has run through, the words are replaced but the formatting of the file is completely broken. I think it's because of getParagraphs. Does anyone know an alternative?

CODE:

```
function anpassen(){
  var varMap={};
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());

  var doc= DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
  var para= doc.getBody().getParagraphs();


  for(var i=0; i<para.length;i++){
    var text=para[i].getText();
    if (!text) continue;


    text=text.replace(/{{([^}]*)}}/g, function(m, $1) {
      if(!varMap[$1]){varMap[$1]= DocumentApp.getUi().prompt($1+"?").getResponseText();
    }
    return varMap[$1];
  });
para[i].setText(text);
}
}
```

Comment: Or is there a possibility to only call paragraphs which contain {{}}?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Advanced Google Services

As specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs#find_and_replace_text) you can use Document API directly by using Google Apps Script, keep in mind that you'll need to import this Advanced Service like the following:

[image]

what's more there's an example of how to [handle the style](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs#insert_and_style_text) while adding a new text.